# Why does /bin/sh point to /bin/dash and not /bin/bash?

Tags: bash, command-line, unity-dash, default

As far as I understand bash is the default shell in Ubuntu, so why does `/bin/sh` point to `/bin/dash`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The default login shell is still `/bin/bash`. What was changed was the default system shell `/bin/sh`.

The change of the default system shell started from Ubuntu 6.10, and the main reason to switch was efficiency.

Here you can find complete information about this change: [*Dash as /bin/sh*](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh)