# Why use env in shebang?

Tags: command-line, bash, environment

What is the purpose of using `#!/usr/bin/env <sh|bash|python>` shebang compared to `#!/bin/bash`, `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/usr/bin/python`?

Comment: There is a good answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88257/what-type-of-path-in-bash-is-more-preferable/88314#88314) in regards to the general use of env.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some people might use a different python (perl, etc.) than the system one. `/usr/bin/env python` would run the version configured as the current one, possibly making the script more portable.

On the other hand, reportedly, some systems do not have `/usr/bin/env`. Also, you cannot use `#!/usr/bin/env foo x` as a replacement for `#!foo x`, because `foo x` will be interpreted as a single argument. So the value of the approach is debatable.

Comment: Configured where? From `info coreutils 'env invocation'` I can see this form of calling makes sure it is external binary instead of shell built-in, but no indication how `env python` would be any different from `python`?

Comment: Your `PATH` probably includes `/usr/local/bin` first. If somebody has manually installed python there, then `env` will call it, whereas `#!/usr/bin/python` will bypass it.

Comment: `virtualenv` is a quite popular tool, and it installs a python executable in the working directory. You would need the `env` trick to get it to work correctly.

Comment: @Tuminoid: you are right: `env python` is the same as `python`. However the problem is that you can't write a shebang like `#!python`: you need to specify a full path.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#!/usr/bin/python
```

The first one is more portable. [source1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908143/should-i-put-shebang-in-python-scripts-and-what-form-should-it-take). [source2](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/finding-bash-perl-python-portably-using-env.html). [source3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612980/why-is-usr-bin-env-bash-superior-to-bin-bash). I haven't seen Linux a system where it doesn't work. And this is a general statement - `/usr/bin/env` is often available, other binaries sit around the filesystem wherever they please.