# Why do commented lines in a linux configuration file sometimes work?

Tags: scripts

By a commented line I mean either:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
```

and the comments in `/boot/grub/menu.lst` file as described in [this answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/35992).

It already has a comment, i.e the line begins with a `#`, but still is being interpreted. Why is that so?

Comment: when a "#" is followed by a "!", it is not a comment, but a shebang. see this question from yesterday: http://askubuntu.com/questions/460981/what-is-this-line-at-the-top-of-many-files/460998#460998

Comment: @Sneetsher: This is not a duplicate. The OP means the `#` in `/boot/grub/menu.lst` file.

Comment: the first example is not exactly the best one, this is about something else

Answer (score 19):

Any line that begins with a `#` is a comment in many languages and is ignored by the interpreter (`perl` etc.).

However, if the **first line** of a script in Linux begins with a `#!` ([shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) as it is called), it is not a comment but a directive to the *program loader* to actually run the program specified after `#!` and pass it the name of your file as the last argument.

For example, if the first line is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
```

it means the shell will actually invoke `/usr/bin/perl -w /path/to/the/script` and you don't need to specify a program to run this script, you can run it using

```
/path/to/the/script
```

if you have the permission to run it and it is located on a filesystem supported for execution and the file has the permission to be executed.

For the interpreter, however, this line is always just a comment, so if the script is  executed as:

```
perl /path/to/the/script
```

then the line has no effect. (Thanks to [Ruslan](https://askubuntu.com/users/113421/ruslan) for pointing this out).

Be warned that `#` is not always indicative of a comment. For example, a statement beginning with a `#` in C is [pre-processor directive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) and not a comment.

<strike>In your case, the line is a comment and will be ignored while execution.</strike>

**Update:**

The file you are talking about is a `menu.lst` for which a comment is a line beginning with `##` and not `#`. <sup>[(Source)](http://bapoumba.wordpress.com/2008/03/20/hashes-in-bootgrubmenulst/)</sup>

Comment: Sorry, I mean exactly this: http://superuser.com/questions/35984/booting-up-renders-error-ata1-00-revalidation-failed-errno-5-in-ubuntu

Comment: @user3390767: See the update.

Comment: @Jobin maybe add that if one runs the script as `perl /path/to/the/script`, then this first line _is_ a comment and doesn't change the way `perl` is launched.

Comment: @Ruslan: Thanks for pointing that out, updated.

Comment: It is *always* a comment to the interpreter, regardless of how the process gets started. That is, the kernel doesn't hide the first line of the file from the interpreter when you do `./file` - the interpreter still sees it.

Comment: Yes, just the loader does parse this line, so for it it's not a comment.

Comment: *+1*: This is very useful. You might consider adding the correct term (shebang) to the answer as well :)

Comment: @AmalMurali: Thanks for pointing that out, done!

Answer (score 2):

The line beginning with `#!` is still a comment, in that it is not executed as normal commands.

But not only is it a valid comment but it's also a *hashbang*, a line that can be used to indicate the interpreter to be used to execute these commands if the script is called on its own.

Hashbangs begin with a `#` in order to be backward-compatible with interpreters that don't read hashbangs, in which case they will simply be interpreted as comments and ignored.