# What version of Python do I have?

Tags: python

How can I find out what versions of Python I have?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr).

Comment: Also, a quick way to see what python binaries are installed is  : `ls /usr/bin | grep python`

Comment: @TejasKale Better to run `ls /usr/bin/python*` (or `ls /usr/bin/*python*` if you *really* want files with `python` *anywhere* in the name). That way, `ls` still formats its output for a terminal (and you get multiple columns and, with the default `ls` alias in Ubuntu, colorization).

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You can use `python -V` (et al.) to show you the version of Python that the `python` command resolves to. If that's all you need, you're done. But to see every version of python in your system takes a bit more.

In Ubuntu we can check the resolution with `readlink -f $(which python)`. In default cases in 14.04 this will simply point to `/usr/bin/python2.7`.

We can chain this in to show the version of that version of Python:

```
$ readlink -f $(which python) | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo -n "%: "; % -V'
/usr/bin/python2.7: Python 2.7.6
```

But this is still only telling us what our current `python` resolution is. If we were in a Virtualenv (a common Python stack management system) `python` might resolve to a different version:

```
$ readlink -f $(which python) | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo -n "%: "; % -V'
/home/oli/venv/bin/python: Python 2.7.4
```

This is real output.

The fact is there could be hundreds of different versions of Python secreted around your system, either on paths that are contextually added, or living under different binary names (like `python3`).

If we assume that a Python binary is always going to be called `python<something>` and  be a binary file, we can just search the entire system for files that match those criteria:

```
$ sudo find / -type f -executable -iname 'python*' -exec file -i '{}' \; | awk -F: '/x-executable; charset=binary/ {print $1}' | xargs readlink -f | sort -u | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo -n "%: "; % -V'
/home/oli/venv/bin/python: Python 2.7.4
/media/ned/websites/venvold/bin/python: Python 2.7.4
/srv/chroot/precise_i386/usr/bin/python2.7: Python 2.7.3
/srv/chroot/trusty_i386/usr/bin/python2.7: Python 2.7.6
/srv/chroot/trusty_i386/usr/bin/python3.4: Python 3.4.0
/srv/chroot/trusty_i386/usr/bin/python3.4m: Python 3.4.0
/usr/bin/python2.7: Python 2.7.6
/usr/bin/python2.7-dbg: Python 2.7.6
/usr/bin/python3.4: Python 3.4.0
/usr/bin/python3.4dm: Python 3.4.0
/usr/bin/python3.4m: Python 3.4.0
/web/venvold/bin/python: Python 2.7.4
```

It's obviously a pretty hideous command but this is again real output and it seems to have done a fairly thorough job.

Comment: I'm getting, the following, and I'm not sure what it means:

`readlink: extra operand '/usr/bin/python2.7'`
`Try 'readlink --help' for more information.`

Comment: i assumed `python -v` would return the version and executed this as root. it printed out a long list of things, but at the top it said `installing zipimport hook` and now it seems as if i'm in a program which i have no idea how to get out of, let alone uninstall?? can you help me out here

Comment: @Anthony The `-V` flag for version is case-sensitive. `python -v` put you in a Python console with verbose messages turned on. Control + D to get out. Or write `exit()` and press return.

Comment: @hello_there_andy I guess you made a typo when you copied the command.

Comment: I missed several virtualenvs using this command. Not sure why though.

Comment: Hi @Oli, thank you for the detailed answer, makes sense. I had a few more questions about this as when I run it it didn't pick up all the versions. 

e.g.  if I run "python --version" or "python3 --version", in both cases I get "Python 3.7.6", which if I run your command I get all sorts of versions apart from 3.7.6 i.e. I get 3.6.9 files, 3.9.13, older version of 3.5.2 but nowhere 3.7.6

Also, I run "which python" and "which python3" to see where it's taking it from, and seems to be picking it up from my anaconda3 installation:

/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python3 

Any suggestions why?

Comment: @Angelo `echo $PATH` should tell you the what, but I can't explain why. I'm not familiar with conda. There may be something in ~/.bashrc or elsewhere automatically setting the path.

Answer (score 68):

Type following in the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
python -V
```

or

```
python --version
```

---

You can  find a list of options/parameters for many commands in the terminal by typing the command followed by *--help*

Example:

```
python --help
```

Manual/manpages also available for most of such CLI which can be displayed by `man <command>` (Ex: `man python`)

From `man python`:

```
COMMAND LINE OPTIONS
        -V ,  --version
              Prints the Python version number of the executable and exits.
```

There is also `python3` installed on many machines, so you can do:

```
python3 --version
```

to find out what python 3.x you are running.

Comment: It's worth noting, as @Florian Diesch below alludes to that you likely have multiple versions of "python". The default "python" call points to an installation of python 2.7, though ubuntu 14.04 comes with python 3.0 as well.

Answer (score 40):

```
python --version
```

and

```
python2 --version
```

show the version of Python 2.x,

```
python3 --version
```

the installed version of Python 3.x

Answer (score 20):

If you want to see all versions of Python available as commands in Bash, run `compgen -c python`. E.g:

```
$ compgen -c python | sort -u
python
python2
python2.7
python3
python3.4
python3.4m
python3m
```

If you want to get the version of each of the above:

```bash
compgen -c python | sort -u | grep -v -- '-config$' | while read -r p; do
    printf "%-14s  " "$p"
    "$p" --version
done
```

```
python         Python 2.7.6
python2        Python 2.7.6
python2.7      Python 2.7.6
python3        Python 3.4.3
python3.4      Python 3.4.3
python3.4m     Python 3.4.3
python3m       Python 3.4.3
```

**Notes**:

- This ignores aliases. For example if I had `alias python=python3`, the above would still show 2.7 for `python`. To include aliases, you could use `eval` (though this might be unsafe):

  ```bash
  eval "$p --version"
  ```
- I'm filtering out the `python*-config` programs with `grep -v` since they don't support the `--version` flag. For example:

  ```
  $ python3-config --version
  Usage: /usr/bin/python3-config --prefix|--exec-prefix|--includes|--libs|--cflags|--ldflags|--extension-suffix|--help|--abiflags|--configdir
  ```

Comment: This should be the top answer, I guess.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work under `zsh`. I guess `compgen` is bash specific? Or at least, it seems to exist in `zsh` as well, but `compgen -c python | wc -l` reports over 6000 matches for me, making it pretty useless.

Comment: @bluenote10 Bash-specific, yeah. I edited to clarify. `compgen` doesn't even exist in my Zsh.

Answer (score 8):

When you run `python` in the terminal, it will produce output like this:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

See the first line - `Python 2.7.6`.

Also run `python3`. I have 3.4.1

```
Python 3.4.1 (default, Jul 31 2014, 12:46:17) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

However, this won't show you them all. If you have 2 or more python 3.X.x versions, you will only see the latest one.

By default on 14.04, you have 2.7.6 and 3.4.0. As you can see, I have updated to 3.4.1. I know that I still have 3.4.0 because when I go to `/usr/bin` I see `python3.4`, and if I run `/usr/bin/python3.4` in the command line, I get 3.4.0, and running `/usr/local/bin/python3.4` gives me 3.4.1

My pronouns are He / Him

Comment: "If you have 2 or more python 3.X.x versions, you will only see the latest one." Won't it instead show whichever one has its containing directory listed first in the `PATH` environment variable? Why would running `python3` always run the *highest* (sub)version of python3 that is installed? Or, in practice, won't it show whatever version the `/usr/bin/python3` symbolic link points to, which need not be the latest?

Comment: @Eliah No idea, but some programs take it from there and others from the `/usr/bin` one...

Comment: Well, when it comes to actually running python programs, depending on how they are run, the [hashbang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) may be used to determine which python acts as the interpreter ([details](http://askubuntu.com/q/238002); also note [the use of `env` in hashbang lines](http://askubuntu.com/q/246955/22949) to find [whichever interpreted may be system-preferred](http://askubuntu.com/q/88257/22949) in [common in Python scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2429511/1038860)). I'm not sure if that's what you mean by differences between some programs and others.

Comment: No, a user said that idle ran with 3.4.0 and command line with 3.4.1...

Answer (score 6):

You can also check Python version from code itself using `platform` module from standard library. There are two functions: `platform.python_version()` (returns string) and `platform.python_version_tuple()` (returns tuple). Script:

```
import platform

print(platform.python_version())
print(platform.python_version_tuple())
```

Running:

```
$ python test.py 
3.4.1
('3', '4', '1')
$ python2.7 test.py 
2.7.8
('2', '7', '8')
```

Comment: I think it's more common to use `sys.version` or `sys.version_info`.

Answer (score 2):

Easily, open the terminal and do the following:

Write

```
python
```

to verify your 2.x version
In my case, it will appear:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

For the 3.x, write:

```
python3
```

In my case, it appears:

```
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

For both cases, to get out from Python shell, write:

```
 exit()
```

Answer (score 2):

- In shell terminal

  `$ which -a python` lists all your `python`.

  `$ which -a python2.7` lists all your `python2.7`.

  `$ /usr/bin/python -V` gives information about the version of `/usr/bin/python`.
- check in python script

here is an ilustration in ipython shell:

```
In [1]: import sys

In [2]: sys.version
2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:08:32) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]

In [3]: sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=11, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

In [4]: sys.version_info >= (2,7)
Out[4]: True

In [5]: sys.version_info >= (3,)
Out[5]: False
```

Comment: i assumed `python -v` would return the version and executed this as root. it printed out a long list of things, but at the top it said `installing zipimport hook` and now it seems as if i'm in a program which i have no idea how to get out of, let alone uninstall?? can you help me out here

Comment: @oldboy hoping you recovered somehow, small-v `python -v` means interactive interpreter in verbose mode, with a freakish flood of detail. Big-v `python -V` gets the version. Exiting the interpreter is easy and consistent. It's either `Ctrl-Z` or `Ctrl-D` or `Ctrl-Break` or `exit()` or `quit()` or `sys.exit()`. Okay it's the opposite of easy and consistent.

Answer (score 0):

For bash script to recognize which python command to use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

usage() {
    echo "Put your help/usage explanation here"
    exit 1
}

get_python_version_to_use() {
    if python3 --version 2>&1 | grep -q "Python 3" ; then 
        echo "python3"
    elif python --version 2>&1 | grep -q "Python 3"; then
        echo "python"
    elif python --version 2>&1 | grep -q "Python 2" ; then 
        echo "python"
    else 
        echo "Error: Python not found";
        usage
    fi
}

PYTHON_COMMAND=$(get_python_version_to_use)
echo $PYTHON_COMMAND
```

Now you can use it to run your script in the bash shell:

```
PYTHON_COMMAND=$(get_python_version_to_use)

$PYTHON_COMMAND my_script.py
```

And it will use python3 or python2 according to what installed on your machine (Preferring python3)