# Why Netbeans not detecting Python?

Tags: python, netbeans

I am using Netbeans IDE 8.0 in my system 14.04 LTS.

I have installed Python plugin in Netbeans 8.0 by following this [link](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/python_in_netbeans_ide_8).

And also I have download `python-3.4.1.tgz` from this [link](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.1/Python-3.4.1.tgz) and installed it as following in terminal,

```
tar -xvf Python-3.4.1.tgz
cd Python-3.4.1/
./configure
make
sudo make install
./python
```

I got result at last as,

```
arul@arul-Aspire-5740:~/Python-3.4.1$ ./python
Python 3.4.1 (default, Sep 19 2014, 17:14:45) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I confirmed by using following command in terminal

```
python3 -V
```

got response as,

```
Python 3.4.1
```

But when I click `Auto Detect` in Python Platform Manager (Netbeans IDE 8.0.1) am am not getting 3.4.1 in the list(Shown below).

[image]

How to solve it ?

**UPDATE 1**

I tried,

```
 arul@arul-Aspire-5740:~$ sudo find / -type f -executable -iname 'python*' -exec file -i '{}' \; | awk -F: '/x-executable; charset=binary/ {print $1}' | xargs readlink -f | sort -u | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo -n "%: "; % -V'
```

And I got result as,

```
[sudo] password for arul: 
/home/arul/Python-3.4.1/python: Python 3.4.1
/usr/bin/python2.7: Python 2.7.6
/usr/bin/python3.4: Python 3.4.0
/usr/bin/python3.4m: Python 3.4.0
/usr/local/bin/python3.4: Python 3.4.1
/usr/local/bin/python3.4m: Python 3.4.1
```

It's showing 3.4.1 but why not Netbeans detecting?

Comment: @IAnsari How it is duplicate ?

Comment: How have you installed 3.4.1?

Comment: Could you execute this command `sudo find / -type f -executable -iname 'python*' -exec file -i '{}' \; | awk -F: '/x-executable; charset=binary/ {print $1}' | xargs readlink -f | sort -u | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo -n "%: "; % -V'` and add output to answer. It will show all python installed. Here is [source](http://askubuntu.com/questions/505081/what-version-of-python-do-i-have)

Comment: @muru I have updated in question that how I installed python 3.4.1, please take a look..

Comment: @ARUL why don't you execute command that I mentioned? May be you only need to create symlink to your python 3.4.1 directory

Comment: Have you tried adding it using the "new" button on the window?  Seems like you could add all the required info that way.

Comment: @ARUL It also tells how Python 3.4.1 goes undetected.

Comment: @c0rp I have updated the result in my question.. please take a look...

Comment: @JohnKirchner Also tried `new` nothing works...

Comment: Are you sure it supports Python3?

Comment: @arsaKasra ya, I done the same in windows with Netbeans 7.4

Answer (score 2):

Select "New" there in the "Python Platform Manager".
 
Then It will open a dialog box.
Navigate to `/usr/local/bin` and select python3.4.
AT least that works on Windows.

If the dialog box does not appear, then in the command field of the new profile type

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.4
```

and in Console Command type the same thing.
In platform name type Python 3.4.1
That will fix your problem.

Don't forget to award the bounty!

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu after I changed all instances of `/usr/local/bin` to just `/usr/bin`