# Ubuntu 21.04 Unknown owner:group of /run/usr/1000/doc - Even root don't have permissions

Tags: permissions, root, 21.04

While executing `sudo updatedb`, I stumbled upon:

```
/usr/bin/find: '/run/user/1000/doc': Permission denied
/usr/bin/find: '/run/user/1000/gvfs': Permission denied
```

So I did `sudo su` and tried to `cd` into it, but surprisingly even as *root* I couldn't access

Here is the listing of the parent dir:

```
root  PC  /run/user/1000  ls -lah
ls: cannot access 'doc': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'gvfs': Permission denied
total 8.0K
drwx------ 13 kolimnared kolimnared 480 May  9 18:45 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root       root        60 May 10 07:35 ..
srw-rw-rw-  1 kolimnared kolimnared   0 May  9 18:17 bus
drwx------  3 kolimnared kolimnared  60 May  9 18:17 dbus-1
drwx------  2 kolimnared kolimnared  60 May 10 14:40 dconf
d?????????  ? ?          ?            ?            ? doc
prw-rw-r--  1 kolimnared kolimnared   0 May  9 18:17 gnome-session-leader-fifo
drwx------  3 kolimnared kolimnared  60 May  9 18:17 gnome-shell
drwx------  2 kolimnared kolimnared 140 May  9 18:17 gnupg
d?????????  ? ?          ?            ?            ? gvfs
drwx------  2 kolimnared kolimnared 260 May 10 14:35 gvfsd
-rw-------  1 kolimnared kolimnared 302 May  9 18:17 ICEauthority
drwx------  2 kolimnared kolimnared 120 May  9 19:35 keyring
-rw-------  1 kolimnared kolimnared  92 May  9 18:17 .mutter-Xwaylandauth.SE7U20
srw-rw-rw-  1 kolimnared kolimnared   0 May  9 18:17 pipewire-0
-rw-rw----  1 kolimnared kolimnared   0 May  9 18:17 pipewire-0.lock
srw-rw-rw-  1 kolimnared kolimnared   0 May  9 18:17 pk-debconf-socket
drwx------  2 kolimnared kolimnared  80 May  9 18:17 pulse
srw-rw-rw-  1 kolimnared kolimnared   0 May  9 18:17 snapd-session-agent.socket
drwx------  3 kolimnared kolimnared  80 May  9 18:17 snap.snap-store
drwxr-xr-x  6 kolimnared kolimnared 160 May  9 18:17 systemd
-rw-------  1 kolimnared kolimnared   0 May  9 18:18 update-notifier.pid
srwxrwxr-x  1 kolimnared kolimnared   0 May  9 18:17 wayland-0
-rw-rw----  1 kolimnared kolimnared   0 May  9 18:17 wayland-0.lock
```

My wild guess is, that this is bug in the newly released 21.04...

Any Ides, what could cause it, or how to fix it?(I mean... except rm -rf /* :) )

Comment: There's nothing to fix - see for example [Why does the find command blow up in /run/?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/839544/why-does-the-find-command-blow-up-in-run)

Comment: Thank you, now I understand :)

Comment: Yes :) This does answer my question!